# In ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - passing list of object to controller with model object

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model class like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModel> ViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC, from js file posting data as shown here:

```
let postedModel = {
     CreatedBy :null,
     CreatedDate :null,
     ViewModel : []
}

postedModel.CreatedBy = "some id";
postedModel.CreatedDate = "today date"

$(".form-fieldset").each(function () {
    let formObject = {};
    $('form').find('input').each(function (index, element) {
        //In cshtml Name attribute given without form index
        formObject[$(element).attr('name')] = $(element).val();
    })
    postedModel.ViewModel.push(formObject)
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/ApiController/SaveData',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(postedModel),
    async: false
})
```

My api controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveData([FromBody] DataModel postedModel)
{
}
```

but I am getting `null` in the api controller.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: The type of `CreatedBy` and  `Id` are `int` instead of 'string' in your javascript? I test your code and it works well, You need to confirm the type is correct.

Comment: when I commented ```postedModel.ViewModel``` model data remaining data getting on controller. again if uncommented same issue model is ```null``` on controller

Comment: Please provide the json of request in network .

Comment: Thanks for your help, you given me valuable hints. problem resolved, one of the property defined as string but json object passing as int, I converted to string and got data.